How can I access data.user variables in lib/components in sveltekit that are already defined in layout.server.ts?
I am using Sveltekit 4, with Supabase SSR for authentication.  I can successfully access user session data from any route pages, but not from any components.
Here is my src/routes/+layout.server.ts
import type { LayoutServerLoad } from './$types';

export const load: LayoutServerLoad = async ({ locals: { getSession } }) => {
    const session = await getSession();
    return {        
        session
    };
};

and my src/routes/+page.svelte can successfully access a logged in user's details:
<script lang="ts">
    export let data;
</script>

{#if data.user}
    <h2>Welcome {data.user.email}</h2>
{/if}

how can I also access this logged in user detail in src/lib/components/Navigation.svelte where I would want the following to work:
<script lang="ts">
    export let data: any;
</script>

<h2>Not logged on</h2>

{#if data.user}
<h2>{data.user.email}</h2>
{/if}

My understanding is that data in layout.server.ts would be available  in all routes and components, how do I make it available in my component?

You can pass data through prop down to component or use store.
When it comes to user session you can use $page store:
// src/routes/+layout.server.ts load function
return {        
    session
}

// your +page.svelte
import { page } from '$app/stores'
// access session with
$page.data.session


As we learned earlier, Svelte stores are a place to put data that
doesn't belong to an individual component.
SvelteKit makes three readonly stores available via the $app/stores
module — page, navigating and updated. The one you'll use most often
is page, which provides information about the current page

https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/page-store
